# Laptop Motherboard Schematics

Tags: schematics

I am working on a bunch of Hp laptop motherboards. These models are variations of HP 15-f Models

They have different model numbers but the boards PCB looks the same just different variations of the components on them.

I need schematics and board viewers for HP motherboards

Model Variations of the HP 15 F

HP 15 F039wm
DAU88MMB6AO
786899-501

HP 15-F
DAOU83MB6EO REV E
782103-501

HP 15-F
DAOU93MB6DO REV D
776783-501

does anyone know where is a good source to locate them?

I looked in Laptop-Schematics.com and they don't have them.

any help is appreciated.

thanks and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

You won't find one.

Schematics are not the sort of information they will publicly release. They'll have copies internally, and possibly distribute them on demand to their repair centres. But they won't release them to anyone.

Comment: Due to pervasive Trojan activity and commercial espionage, many major devices have schematics leaked online, however finding a specific Rev of a specific PN  is unlikely

Comment: @crasic well ok, but I was working from a above board point of view. You certainly wont find a "**good** source" for them.

Comment: Thanks guys- I found a few paid $10 for them from http://laptop-schematics.com